# Change Cypress to wait more than 20s in a response

Tags: testing, cypress

I'm trying to prepare a test that's capable to wait more than 20s for a response. But even if i try to set timeout on wait() function, it doesn't respect the option.

```
cy.visit('http:site')
cy.intercept('GET', '**/slowEndpoint**').as('slow')

cy.get('[data-qa-id="btnCallsEndpoint"]').click()
cy.wait('@slow', {timeout: 60000}) // should do the magic

//This button is in another page, so for that, i CANT put the timeout option in here
cy.get('[data-qa-id="btnAvailableAfterResponseOK"]').click()
```

Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: what is the error you are getting ?

Comment: No error. Cypress was not considering my timeout option. Was using the default, 4000ms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figure it out, the problem is that i'm putting the cy.intercept() on beforeEach(), for that it doesn't work. If i put right before the wait(), inside the test, it works!

Don't know if this is the right behaviour, but i'll change here.

Answer (score 0):

It might be that the intercept is being registered too late. Try putting the intercept before the visit command. This might do the trick. Everything else looks good to me.